# UseMauiEmbedding causing NavigationController to become Null

Tags: xamarin.ios, maui, .net-7.0

Trying to embed a MAUI contentView into an existing migrated Xamarin project (now migrated to .Net7)
For the iOS build when running and the `builder.UseMauiEmbedding` is commented out it runs fine and the NavigationController is detected.

If I uncomment the code while the splash screen is loading and the NavigationController.Parent is fetched, the NavigationController returns as NULL with no other changes

AppDelegate

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            ...
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

            //Add Maui Controls - when adding this the navigationController becomes null
            builder.UseMauiEmbedding<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application>();
            return true;
        }
```

MenuController (with the code commented it fetches NavigationController, when uncommented it crashes with a null fetch)

```
private HomeController HomeController
        {
            get
            {
                return (NavigationController.ParentViewController as SlideoutNavigationController).TopView as HomeController;
            }
        }
```

Crash output which points to the above code and when debugging NavigationController is now null

2023-08-30 15:57:09.129 LIC.MINDAMobile.iOS[15792:11028708] [AppCenterXamarinCrashes] ERROR: +[MSACWrapperLogger MSACWrapperLog:tag:level:]/10 Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at LIC.MINDAMobile.iOS.MenuController.get_HomeController() in /Users/stall1/Projects/LIC/mobile-minda/LIC.MINDAMobile.iOS/Controllers/MenuController.cs:line 51
at LIC.MINDAMobile.iOS.MenuController.ViewDidLoad() in /Users/stall1/Projects/LIC/mobile-mi

Trying to get the mauiContext with a the standard builder so that I can open a Maui ContentView from inside a .Net 7 Xamarin project (ios)

Soon as I add the line above the rest of the system can no longer find the navigationController

Comment: Have you tried the complete method in official documents : [Native embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/native-embedding)?

Comment: _To consume .NET MAUI types that derive from Element in native apps, create an instance of the control..._ [Consume .NET MAUI controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/native-embedding#consume-net-maui-controls)